# Closing a thread handle before exiting the associated thread

Tags: c++, c, windows-ce

This is what I am trying to do in my code:
I create an event, create a thread. If something fails in the main thread, I set the event to indicate the associated thread about the failure and instruct it to gracefully exit the associated thread.

My question is, is it safe to close the thread handle, right after the event is set, while the associated thread is still running (trying to clean up and exit)? The intention in trying to close the thread handle immediately and not waiting for the associated thread to return is to avoid stalling others waiting on the main thread until the associated thread returns.

Pleases suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.  From the [`CreateThread` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The thread object remains in the system until the thread has terminated and all handles to it have been closed through a call to `CloseHandle`.

Of course, if you close the thread's handle, then you can no longer wait on it via a call to `WaitForSingleObject`/`WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I don't want to wait for the associated thread to return (unless it is going to create a problem). So, I don't need the handle once the thread is created and started running. I am taking care of cleaning up and gracefully exiting the associated thread in case something goes wrong with it. So, I am assuming it should be safe/legal to close the handle and even exit the main thread while the associated thread is still running.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a sin to close the thread handle even within your Thread function but the thing is you will not be able to use that thread handle for any communication. other option is Wherever you are signalling the event use waitforsingleobject and wait on the thread handle. Once it returns you can close the handle.